# Slightly Complicated SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Write an SQL query that returns number of articles by user, as the following results with the column header: 'user_id', 'username', 'total_count_of_articles' order by number of articles
[image]

Comment: What are you using? Are you just trying to get it through SQL? I know that I use PHP to do all the counting work...

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I've downvoted, as we like to see research effort here - especially since the question hasn't even been modified from the wording on the homework paper. Please give it a go, and someone will help.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do this through SQL, please help!

Comment: No, you're not trying to do this at all. You're trying to get free coding done for you.

Comment: @ilarsona don't count via PHP! use count(), use sum() use whatever, but get it via MySQL

Comment: I dont understand the hostility, Im new at SQL and i wasnt looking for an exact answer, just give me an example if nothing else..

Comment: One of the boldest "questions" I've ever seen. Reads more like an order.

Comment: The hostility comes from the fact that your "question" looks almost identical to a question you would see out of a sql 101 course / class. It looks to me like you flat up copy pasted the question from your course book.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query prob that returns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819774/sql-query-prob-that-returns)

Comment: Its not a duplicate. i posted it, and with my work this time..im not allowed to ask hw questions or something?

Comment: so, why you posted it twice?

Comment: because its not the same question..did you even look at it?

Comment: Hi @user3490625: the consensus is you are allowed to ask homework questions. But the overwhelming feedback you've received here is that research is required, and you seem to have fought against it (and asked another unresearched question) notwithstanding. This feedback is **not hostile**. It is valuable feedback, and the feedback is essentially this: (a) we'll put in as much effort as you do, and (b) you'll only learn something if you put effort in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should return the specified resultset:

```
 SELECT u.id AS user_id
      , u.user_name
      , SUM(a.user_id IS NOT NULL) AS total_count_of_articles
   FROM users u
   LEFT
   JOIN users_articles a
     ON a.user_id = u.id
  GROUP BY u.id, u.user_name
  ORDER BY total_count_of_articles DESC
```

Comment: Just use `COUNT(a.user_id)`. Fix your column names. E.g. there is no `users.user_id` column.

Comment: Right on about the column name being wrong, that is fixed. And you are right that COUNT(a.user_id) will return an equivalent result. I think that for a beginner (who views this type of query being "slightly complicated"), the `SUM(a.user_id IS NOT NULL)` is terse enough; I think it serves to highlight the idea that we are not  "counting" rows where a.user_id is null. We could also write it as: `SUM(IF(a.user_id IS NOT NULL,1,0))`.