# How to finish this homework SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the homework question I have:

> Write an SQL query that returns from user_id, username, email from table 'user', title of 'article', content of 'comments' for all the articles are created in 2013.

This is my solution so far:

```
Select user_id, users_username, users_email, articles_title, articles_created, comments_content
from comments
inner join users
   on comments.user_id = users.id
inner join users
   on comments.articles_id = articles.id
where created > = '2013/01/01' AND '2014/01/01';
```

Here is the ERD:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I suggest you include what you've got so far, even if it's just `SELECT * FROM users`, and ask a question. Just pasting your homework question isn't going to score you any points here.

Comment: I did include my work...

Comment: `where created > = '2013/01/01' AND '2014/01/01'` doesn't do what you think it does.  You probably want `where created >= '2013/01/01' AND created < '2014/01/01'` OR `where created BETWEEN '2013/01/01' AND '2013/12/31'`

Comment: @MarcusAdams: He said "created in 2013".  I'd assume he doesn't want `'2014/01/01'`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, Does MySQL recognize dates in that format?

Comment: @MarcusAdams:  Also, you're right about the date formats.  It should be `2013-01-01` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should return the specified resultset:

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id
     , u.username
     , u.email
     , a.title
     , c.created
     , c.content
  FROM comments c
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = c.user_id
  JOIN articles a
    ON a.id = c.articles_id
 WHERE c.created >= '2013-01-01' 
   AND c.created <  '2014-01-01'
 ORDER BY u.id, c.created
```

---

If you want to understand SQL, it's important that you work through the problems, and understand how the query text is being interpreted.

Some notes:

- Don't put spaces between the two characters in the `>=` operator (I'm fairly certain that's not valid; even if it is, don't do it.)
- The AND is a logical operator,  `"foo >= x AND y"` isn't comparing `"foo"` to `"y"`, it's evaluating `"foo >= x"` as a boolean (returning true, false or null), it's evaluating `"y"` as a boolean (returning true, false, or null), and then `"AND"` is doing a logical AND operation on the two booleans. That's valid syntax, but it's not the operations you intended.
- Date literals in MySQL should always in the form `'YYYY-MM-DD'`; later versions of MySQL are more lenient about the separator character and the two positions for the month and day, but the four-dash-two-dash-two format is the standard.
- Best practice is to qualify column references with table name or table alias, the dot character separates the table name/alias from the column
- The `"users_username"` reference in your query is an invalid identifier. There isn't any column by that name in any table referenced by the query. It looks like you meant that to specify the `"username"` column from the `"users"` table, which would be referenced as `"users.user_name"`, using the dot character to separate the the two identifiers. Same for the other column references in your SELECT list
- The `"INNER"` keyword is redundant, it's unnecessary and makes no difference in the query; in MySQL `"JOIN"` and `"INNER JOIN"` are synonymous.  (It's also synonymous with `"CROSS JOIN"`, though we typically do include the `"CROSS"` keyword when there are no join predicates, even though it's not required. This is mostly a documentation aid for the future reader, who will be looking for JOIN predicates, the `"CROSS"` keyword gives them a clue that the "missing" JOIN predicates are intentional, and not just a mistake or oversight.

Also note: a SQL statement is READ many more times than it is WRITTEN; so, format the SQL so it's easy for a reader to decipher and comprehend what the statement is doing.

As an example, compare the query above, to the equivalent:

```
select users.id as user_id,users.username as username,users.email as email,articles.title,
comments.created, comments.content from comments inner join users on comments.user_id=
users.id join articles on comments.articles_id=articles.id where comments.created >=
'2013-01-01' and comments.created < '2014-01-01' order by users.id, comments.created
```

Then answer the following questions, looking at the SQL:

- how many columns does this query return?
- which columns are returned from the comments table?
- how many tables are involved?
- are there any outer joins operations?
- are there any aggregates in the select list?
- etc.

The formatting of the SQL is an aid to the future reader. The real benefit reveals itself with more complicated SQL (involving multiple tables, aggregates, inline views, complex expressions, correlated subqueries, and so on.)

Comment: I'll add +1 here, but I have reservations about offering so much help to someone who has demonstrated limited effort, twice. I'm in two minds as to whether it helps their own learning process, but quite sure it doesn't help in the general fight against help vampirism.

Comment: @halfer: I understand what you are saying, and I agree with you; but OP did take effort to seek help by posting a question. I think a couple of examples can help bridge the gap between sparse examples in the documentation, and getting some code working. And better a good example than a bad one.